# SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have this query below and i want to convert it to Laravel Eloquent. I have tried with no success.

```
select A.client_id, max(A.purchase_date)
from gym_client_purchases A
left Join gym_clients B on B.id = A.client_id
group by A.client_id
order By max(A.purchase_date) desc
```

I tried this but i get the oldest record from each user.

```
$this->data['expiringSubscriptions'] = Gym::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'gym_client_purchases.*')
->leftJoin('gym_clients', 'gym_clients.id', '=', 'client_id')
->groupBy('client_id')
->orderBy('gym_client_purchases.purchase_date', 'desc')
->get();
```

Could anyone guide me to convert my queries?

Thank you.

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far - this is a pretty trivial query so your solution might not take a lot of tweaking.

Comment: I'm going to guess that with the `max()` functions, you may not be using `DB::raw()` where you need it

Comment: @aynber I updateted my question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any models, so here it is using the query builder.

```
$results = DB::table('gym_client_purchases gcp')
    ->selectRaw('gcp.client_id, MAX(gcp.purchase_date) AS max_purchase_date')
    ->leftJoin('gym_clients gc', 'gc.id', '=', 'gcp.client_id')
    ->groupBy('gcp.client_id')
    ->orderBy('max_purchase_date', 'desc');
```

Haven't run it - but that should be basically it.